# How to add an image to a dialog form with jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I am working on MVC application and on one of my pages I have an image gallery. I want to do the following: when I click on any given image to open a modal dialog and display the image (the reason for that is because I don't have much space on my page).

Javascript code:

```
 function openDialog(url)
{
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
    document.getElementById("dialog-form").style ="display: block;"
    document.getElementById("modalImg").src = url;

}

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 800,
    width: 850,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {

        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

Razer View:

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 100%;">


            @foreach (var photo in Model.Application.Screenshots.Where(p => p.Device == 1))
            {
                <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
                    <img alt='Patka' src='@Url.Content(photo.Url)' width='250' onclick="openDialog('@Url.Content(photo.Url)')"/>
                </div>

            }

            <div id="dialog-form" title="Screenshot Preview" style="display: none;">
                <img alt='ModalPatka' id="modalImg" src=".."/>
            </div>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
```

However when I click on any image nothing happens. Any idea why?

Comment: `.dialog` is not a method of jquery's, so I assume you as using a jQuery plugin to provide this.  Which one?  jQuery UI?

Comment: yep Jquery-ui-1.8.24.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any javascript errors in your console (Firebug for Firefox or the Chrome debug console)?  I am not sure of the exact problem, but I can say that you should probably clean up your javascript and use the full power of jQuery selectors, this might help solve your issue.

Here are the changes that I would recommend:

1. Place a class on your preview images so that we can attach a jQuery handler to the click of that element.
2. I am not sure if .src is a valid jQuery selector on an element.  Try using the .attr() designator
3. Let's remove the GetElementById calls in your JavaScript and use the jQuery selectors
4. I think the dialog call needs to be in your .Ready jQuery function. See the examples [here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)
5. Update your DOM elements before calling the .Dialog function to prevent screen flashing.
6. Remove the spaces in your jQuery selectors, I dont think this is causing an issue, but it would not hurt to clean those up as well (e.g. `(this)` instead of `( this )`)..even though the jQuery UI examples have them, maybe this is just a coding style concern.

**JavaScript Code**

```
$(function(){
    $(".OpenDialog").on("click", function(){
        $("#dialog-form").style ="display: block;";
        $("#modalImg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src"));
        $("#dialog-form").dialog({
           autoOpen: false,
           height: 800,
           width: 850,
           modal: true,
           buttons: {    
               Cancel: function() {
                   $(this).dialog("close");
               }
           },
           close: function() {
               allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
           }
       });
    });    
});
```

**Razor View**

```
<div style="height: auto; width: 100%;">
    @foreach (var photo in Model.Application.Screenshots.Where(p => p.Device == 1))
    {
        <div style="float: left; width: 250px;">
            <img alt='Patka' src='@Url.Content(photo.Url)' width='250' class="OpenDialog"/>
        </div>
    }

    <div id="dialog-form" title="Screenshot Preview" style="display: none;">
        <img alt='ModalPatka' id="modalImg" src=".."/>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: when I try it i end up with `0x800a138b - JavaScript runtime error: Cannot assign to a function result` pointing to                       `$("#modalImg").attr("src") = $(this).attr("src");`

Comment: Updated - you have to use .attr("src", value).  My bad

Comment: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'dialog'

Comment: got this two imports: 

`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Are you importing before you are calling the above code?  Also, are they in the order you just typed out?

Comment: yes they are at the beginning of the file, and they are also found in the default script folder of the mvc application, so I think that they can't be causing the problem.

Comment: I would ensure that they are actually being retrieved from the server.  That error sounds like jquery ui is not being loaded.  You were not seeing it before because your function was not actually being called.

Comment: yes, another observation is that if I simply write this in a html file it works perfectly fine, so obviously the problem is in the loading of the jquery. Could there be a problem in the ISS which prevents the loading of the jquery library?

Comment: I would not think so...just double check your file names and paths and ensure that they are an exact match (e.g. jquery-ui.1.8.24 or something like that)